# Как поместить картинку над виджетом text в Tkinter: фон для редактируемого текста

Tags: python, tkinter

Я хотел бы узнать есть ли какая то команда которая поместит картинку на передний план, задать ей прозрачность и заблокировать её, то есть картинка будет выглядеть как фон для текстового редактора

Comment: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm

Comment: Спасибо за наводку, но как это осуществить с помощью PIL

Comment: Я вас правильно понимаю, вы хотите задать фон для окна?

Comment: я хочу создать фон для виджета text

Comment: Тогда спешу вас огорчить что фон для виджета text создать, если я не ошибаюсь, нельзя.

Comment: А не подскажите как возможно осуществить это. То есть у нас есть виджет текст и место белого фона мы видим картинку естественно с прозрачностью какой нибудь. Может есть какие-нибудь идеи

Comment: Честно сказать идей нет. Лучше начините учить PyQt5, в нем намного больше возможностей чем в tkinter.

Comment: Спасибо за совет

Comment: я хочу фон для редактируемого текста

Comment: Можно из canvas сделать некое подобие редактора текста (чтобы печатался текст при нажатии на клавиши, удалялся, вручную рисовать курсор, выделение текста и т.д.), но это не очень простая задача.

Answer (score 1):

я толком не понял что именно надо сделать, но я могу показать как сделать картинку на фон

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()#можно вместо root написать любое название переменной с окном
root.state('zoomed')#это делает полно экранный режим окна
cnv=Canvas(root, width=500, height=500)# вместо root, вписываем название переменной родительского окна и в переменную width вписываем любую ширину для виджета Canvas и в переменную height- его высоту
cnv.pack()# уапковуем Canvas в родительское окно в скобках указываем нужные настройки
img=PhotoImage(file='путь к картинке')# можно любое другое название, кроме img
cnv.create_image(image=img, x=5, y=5) #создает картинку x-пиксели в ширину y- пиксели в длину
```

по-моему все понятно и правильно если нет, то ладно мне просто лень проверять
можно сделать Frame и туда запихнуть картинку, а сверху картинку уже виджет Text

Comment: На будущие, если вы пишите код то надо отступить четыре пробела или нажать K+Ctrl. Пожалуйсто читаете сначала справку перед тем как отвечать