# как в tkinter изображение вынести на верхний слой

Tags: python, tkinter

У меня возникла проблема с изображением. У меня есть виджет Text и картинка на фоне. То есть картинка Text над изображением. Когда я вставляю новую картинку то она становется над виджетом Text. И здесь мне нужна какая то функция чтобы изображение перенести на задний план и Text был на переднем плане

Comment: ИЛИ можно виджет перенести на передний план если это возможно

Comment: чем это отличается от вопроса: [Как поместить картинку над виджетом text в Tkinter: фон для редактируемого текста](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/835132/23044)

Comment: По сути ничем, но я решил проблему

Comment: если "ничем", то старый вопрос обновите, если есть новая информация, которая его уточняет¶ Если думаете, что нашли решение, то там его как свой ответ и опубликуйте—это явно приветствуется http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer